# How to insert text in the middle of the file using node fs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, filesystems, fs

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import userReducer from './user.reducer';
import loaderReducer from './loader.reducer';
import commonReducer from './common.reducer';

const reducerObj = {
  loader: loaderReducer,
  user: userReducer,
  common: commonReducer
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducerObj);

export default rootReducer;
```

I have this file, and I want to edit it dynamically. I want to append one more `import` statement just below the other imports. Also, I want to add another key:value pair in `reducerObj`. I am trying to achieve this using node `fs` module, but its tricky. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: did you try to wrap them into if statments .. whitch case you want the import thing to be added??

Comment: What sort of issue did you run into?  (i.e. your comment "...but it's tricky.")

Comment: This looks like a similar q--might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58582161/is-it-possible-to-write-text-in-the-middle-of-a-file-with-fs-createwritestream